# Difficulties with Jordan normal form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

i'm studying in German and because of corona virus we had only a video lecture, so unfortunately I have not understood how to deal in cases when I do not have the matrix. If I had it, I think I got the steps. But now I have just this table  and I should determine the number of Jordan blocks. If I had the matrix it would be also pretty easy to calculate the characteristic and the minimal polynomial.

> Now let $g : W \to W$ be a nilpotent endomorphism on a $12$-dimensional vector space $W$, over the field $K$, with the dimensions of $\operatorname{ker}g^i$ given by the following table:
>   $$\begin{array}{c|c}
> i & 12 & 11 & 10 & 9 & 8 & 7 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
> \hline
> \dim \operatorname{ker} g^i & 12 & 12 & 12 & 12 & 12 & 12 & 12 & 12 & 11 &10 & 8 & 5 & 0
> \end{array}$$

[Original german](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eD15i.png)

I do not want the whole solution, but only a hint how to determine the matrix.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

The sequence that we need to consider here is sometimes called the "Weyr characteristc" (cf. Horn and Johnson's *Matrix Analysis* for instance).

Since $g$ is nilpotent, its only eigenvalue is zero, and so all Jordan blocks that we refer to are associated with eigenvalue $\lambda = 0$. Let $k_i = \dim \ker g^i$ (note that $\dim \ker g^0 = \dim \ker \operatorname{id} = 0$).  Let $a_i = k_{i} - k_{i-1}$. The number $a_i$ counts the number of Jordan blocks that $g$ has of size at least $i$. You should try to convince yourself that this is indeed the case.

The sequence $(a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots)$ is sometimes called the "Weyr characteristic of $g$ associated with $(g,0)$". With that established, let $b_i = a_i - a_{i-1}$.  By our earlier characterization of $a_i$, we can see that $b_i$ is the number of Jordan blocks of size $i$.

---

So, for our example, consider the following:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
i &   0 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
\hline
k_i & 0 & 5 & 8 & 10\\
\hline
a_i & \cdot & 5-0=5&8-5=3 & 10-8=2\\
\hline
b_i & \cdot & 5-3 = 2 & 3-2 = 1
\end{array}
$$
We can continue in this fashion.

Answer (score 0):

You have the dimensions of the kernels: $5$, $8$, $10$, $11$, $12$, (stabilizes)

Build the Young diagram as follows:

$5$, $5+3=8$, $5+3+2=10$, $5+3+2+1=11$, $5+3+2+1+1=12$

[image: young_diagram]

Now the COLUMNS of the Young diagram will give the sizes of the Jordan cells:  $5$,$3$,$2$,$1$,$1$.

Incidentally, this is a symmetric Young diagram, so the sizes of columns are the sizes of rows...